# RDS 2012 Outlook Roaming Profile

Tags: windows-server-2012, outlook, rds, roaming-profile, microsoft-office-2013

I have a RDS collection with one sever in it with about 50 existing profiles, since day one we have had roaming profiles set-up and folder redirection. I have just added another RD host to the collection for load balancing and it seems the Outlook settings will not roam, it is asking them to setup email on first run. I cannot see what i am missing. all my googling just bring up people trying to stop the OST from roaming, i am really just wanting settings to roam. I dont mind if it has to redoownloand on first run for each server, just dont want them to have to enter details again.

- This is an RDS only environment, all VM on the same host.
- All running Server 2012 R2, Office Standard 2013
- Only one RDS collection
- Outlook is connected to hosted 365, running cached exchange mode and 3 months stored local.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question: Outlook is not supposed to work with Roaming Profiles. Imagine having a 5 gigabyte OST/PST file that needs to be synced every logoff and every logon. Wow... :)

> I dont mind if it has to redoownloand on first run for each server, just dont want them to have to enter details again.

You could try to [Customize Outlook profiles by using an Outlook Profile (PRF) file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062%28v=office.14%29.aspx). That way you can achieve exactly what you just said :)

Comment: Thanks, how would i know the details to put in the profile? These are hosted users, with email outside out domain.

Answer (score -1):

I have used roaming profiles with Outlook for years with no problem.  You just have to redirect the appdata folder and it won't copy the cache back and forth.