# Deploying Outlook through RemoteApp

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, rds, roaming-profile

We have an RDS server where we host our software plus supply access to office and a few other programs. this is a multi tenant environment, we do not host any email or exchange but users can connect outlook to their email so all their need programs are within session.  Now after asking this question [RDS 2012 Outlook Roaming Profile](https://serverfault.com/questions/750058/rds-2012-outlook-roaming-profile/750092#750092) is seems outlook just does not roam and i dont want people to have to reconfigure email every time I add a new server to loan balance.

I was considering setting up a new VM with just office installed on it and deploying this to my other session host via remote apps.  As all folders are redirected i would this it would work pretty smoothly and would not require outlook to roam.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

That would work since that data locations remain the same and are just surfaced in the Roaming profile.

It is quite common on VDI deployment to disable Outlook cached mode so it's running in "online" mode and not storing mail locally.  The downside is this requires a constant connection to Exchange, and for Exchange Online could generate substantial traffic depending on users and usage patterns. You don't have to settle for "online" only, you can mitigate the download times by limiting the amount of data that Outlook Caches. In outlook 2016 you can set this to as little as 3 days.  I believe 2013 is 1 week.